# How to change number format for whole wordpress site?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to change number format for my whole site as different country uses different formats like

- United States  — $1,234,567.89 USD
- Canada           — $1,234,567.89 CAD
- Great Britain   — £1.234.567,89 GBP
- European        — €1.234.567,89 EUR

By default it uses United State format but i need it to be European.

what i can do is use

```
number_format($number, 2, ',', '.');
```

this  simple function, which works fine for me, but i have to use it every time i am working with number,  And i need this to use for once like in wp-config.php  or function.php file and that will change the format for whole site.

Is it possible?

Comment: By supplying examples, you make it seem like you want it to be dynamic. Like when people change the language of the website, the number format (prices) also show up in a different format. Is that what you want? Or you just want to move from US to EU? You are using prices, do you use a webshop plugin or some code you put together yourself?

Comment: Yeah it's dynamic but i do not want it to be connected with language, what i want to do is i will make a option in my option page where admin can select any one format.

actually i am developing a LMS plugin for my client, where i need this function not for only price  also calculation if length, height etc. like if instructor write 200,12 ft it will be like 200.12 ft in frontend.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use wp filter for prepare common function in which you can define number format for different country.

apply_filters( 'number_format_i18n', change_number_format );

[number format i18n](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/number_format_i18n/)

[developer number format i18n](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/number_format_i18n/)

Answer (score 1):

I assume the admin setting of the format is stored in the database.
Read that setting and use the values in constants

```
$setting = array();
$setting = get_option('formatsetting');
const PRECISION = $setting['precision'];
const DECIMALS  = $setting['decimals'];
const THOUSANDS = $setting['thousands'];
```

Then you can use `number_format` like this:

```
number_format($number, PRECISION, DECIMALS, THOUSANDS);
```

You can extend it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using WooCommerce..
You can create a filter that will modify the price's format and then to load it according to your language/currency.

```
function change_product_price_display( $price ) {
    if( $lang == 'EN' ) {
      $price = number_format( $price, 2, ',', '.' ); 
      return $price;
    }

    return $price;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'change_product_price_display' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'change_product_price_display' );
```

Comment: Thanks, But i am not using WooCommerce, And also this format is not about only the price, any number i am using in my site will follow same format like if somewhere it is 2,000 feet it will be 2.000 feet when print or echo ....

Comment: Everywhere WordPress outputs price/currency/anything, there is a theme function calling it to display in a specific way. What you might need is to create your own function and wrap all the outputs in your theme. Unless your theme is already doing it and then you will be able to customize the existing function

Comment: Thanks, this is actually what i planned to do, but i was looking for if there any better option available. :)